# How do I set up Munin to ping all devices in my LAN and alert me if anything is offline?

Tags: ping, local-area-network, munin

So I managed to set up Munin, which was tearful because it was my first encounter with Linux. But it now works and generates colorful little graphs. The real purpose of that exercise, however, was to get Munin to ping all devices within the LAN (ca. 200, not all of them serving as web servers), and alert me whenever anything goes offline. What is the most straightforward way to do that?

Comment: If alerting was what you wanted, perhaps you should have gone with something like Nagios/Icinga?

Comment: well, I had actually tried to ask exactly that, but my question (http://serverfault.com/questions/617180/monitoring-the-status-of-lan-devices) was heavily downvoted. I was eventually advised to install Munin, which I actually like and which seems to do alerts. I just haven't found a straightforward way to ping all devices of the network and report on slow/failed pings.

Comment: Thank you. I habe now set up Nagios. I like it very much. It's best to have both Munin and Nagios though, as you say they serve different purposes.

Comment: Yepp, run both Nagios (Well, Icinga actually) and Munin in parallel myself.